# How do I configure integrated authentication for SQL Server JDBC driver in Eclipse?

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I am trying to create a new database connection to SQL Server in Eclipse, and I am getting the following error:

```
*com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:f76bec48-e9f8-4a03-aea3-4840e8674267*
```

Environment details:

- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (x64)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR)
- Eclipse 4.9.0 JRE 1.8.0_191
- Driver: sqljdbc 6.0

---

Steps that led to the error:

1. Opened Data Source Explorer and added a new Database Connection
2. Chose Microsoft SQL Server 2008 JDBC Driver (I was not able to get any of the newer ones to work; it wouldn't let me enter any properties).
3. Pointed Eclipse to my JAR file (sqljdbc42.jar)
4. Entered the database properties and chose "Use integrated authentication"
5. Clicked "Test Database Connection"

This is where I get the error noted above.

---

What I have tried to fix the error:

- I read that this error is often due to the absence of the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the Windows system path, so I moved the x64 version of this file to C:\Windows\System32 (and I also tried C:\Windows\SysWOW64 for good measure), but, same result.
- I also found that adding the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to the java.library.path value can be a potential fix, but I am not sure how to do that since I am not actually in a project at this point; I am in the Data Source Explorer trying to add a new connection.

---

Every time I try to ping this connection, I get the same error:

```
*com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:733c823d-b740-4f70-89a4-4109a03dad58*
```

However, I am able to connect to this server/database with Windows Authentication via SQL Server Management Studio.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using 32 bit or 64 bit Java?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, sorry I meant to specify that. 64 bit Java.

Answer (score 1):

Late response for anyone who might still run into this... I had to drop a copy of the mssql-jdbc_auth-*X.Y.X*.x64.dll file (from the driver's sqljdbc_*X.Y*\enu\auth\x64 folder) into the java.library.path on my Windows 10 machine and restart eclipse.  After that, I was able to connect using the integrated security. BTW, the java.library.path should, in part, reflect your Windows environment's PATH variable.